# Django templates: if .. in

Tags: python, sql, django, django-templates, backend

I have a list of products and want to display them in a template, depending on whether or not the product's dealer is "owned" by the current logged user or not. So here's my view:

```
class ArticleListView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = "accounts/list_article_quentin.html"
    model = Product
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["website"] = Website.objects.first()
        context["product_list"] = context["product_list"].filter(published=True)
        # Get a list of all dealers associated to the current users.
        currentUserDealers = self.request.user.dealers.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
        context["current_user_dealers"] = list(currentUserDealers)
        return context
```

so currentUserDealers is the list of the dealers associated to the current user (It's a ManyToMany relationship between dealers and users).

Here's the Products and Dealers models (only the relevant parts):

```
class Product(models.Model, CloneMixin):
    published = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=False)
    title = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=200)
    (...)
    dealer = models.ManyToManyField(Dealer, null=True,editable=True,related_name="product_to_dealer")
    (...)
    # Not sure what this does:
   _clone_many_to_many_fields = ['parameter', 'tag', 'category', 'dealer','images']
    (...)

    
class Dealer(models.Model, CloneMixin):
    dealer_check = models.ForeignKey("self",null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    published = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True, default=True)
    (...)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User,null=True,blank=True, related_name='dealers')
    (...)
```

In my template, I would like to do something like that to decide wether to display the product or not:

```
{% if product.dealer.all.0.pk in current_user_dealer %}
```

*(there can be multiple dealers for a product but I'll see that later, hence the all.0)*

Obviously this doesn't work but you get the idea, I want to see if the current product's dealer ID is in the list of current user's associated dealers, to see if we display it or not. What's the syntax to do it in the template? Or maybe there's a better way to do this directly in the view?

Comment: can you show your models?

Comment: @SLDem I edited my post with the models!

Comment: so 1 product can have multiple dealers? I don't understand this logic , however will try to help, give me a couple minutes

Comment: Yes but it's kinda ignored at the moment, that's why I only select the first one. Thanks!

Comment: just do it with a `ForeignKey`, then my answer will work 100%

Comment: That's not my codebase, I can't modify that unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you the correct `product_list` in your template

```
def get_context_data(self):
    context = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['product_list'] = Product.objects.filter(dealer__id_in=self.request.user.dealers.all())
    return context
```

Comment: I had to add **kwargs in the get_context_data() arguments and then got this error:
Related Field got invalid lookup: id_in

Comment: if you want this to work you need to make it a `ForeignKey` relation, if thats not your codebase then you should ask the person who owns it to do it, the reason its not working is because in the query the `dealer` is a `m2m` field and a `m2m` field relations dont have a single id, they store querysets, however `ForeignKey` relations do so if you replace that part it will work

Comment: btw I modified the query a little so you can try that

Comment: Thanks, I'll talk about it but I think the goal is to make it work with multiple dealers that can sell the same product at some point. I tried your edited version but I still get "Related Field got invalid lookup: id_in"